# How does the compiler choose the right function?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, overloading

I wrote a small 3d vector class. In particular I wrote two functions, one for rotating the vector and one intended to return a rotated copy of the vector itself. so I have the followig:

```
Vector Vector::Rotate(const double angle, Vector& axis) const {
Vector b=*this;
b.Rotate(angle,axis);
return (b);
}

void Vector::Rotate(const double angle, Vector & axis) {

/* let's promote this vector to a quaternion */
Quaternion V (0,*this);

/* quaternion describing the rotation */
Quaternion q (cos(angle/2),axis*sin(angle/2));

/* actual rotation  */
*this = (q*V*q.conjugate()).Vec();
}
```

now, when I write something like this:

```
 vector2 = vector1.Rotate(rbo::M_PUCKER,i);
```

I obtain the error:
    no operator "=" matches these operands
    operand types are: Vector = void

I expect the compiler to understand what I want: why does he choose the void version instead of the other one returning a vector? Moreover, is it a good practise writing more versions of the same functions the way I did?

Comment: Good practice? **No**. The semantics are really confusing. Make it clear what the function does.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler picks the `const` or non-`const` overload depending solely on the object on which the member function is called. If the object (or reference) is `const` it will pick the `const` overload.

Is it good practice? No. As it seems obvious from the fact that you got yourself confused on what the compiler should do. It is usually good practice to write code that can be easily read and interpreted without confusion :)

Comment: why is that so? I thought declaring a method as const just prevents it from accidentally modifying a class's member variables. So, why does the call depend on the object?

Comment: There is a bit of a double meaning to "const" on a method. 1. Tell the compiler that the object will not change. 2. Tell the compiler which function to call if there is an overload without "const". I find this confusing as well. If anybody knows why it is the way it is, I would be interested. :)

Comment: @MarcDuQuesne: That is just how the rules for overload resolution are handled, and it is exactly the same as in other contexts: `void f(int&); void f(const int&); int i; f(i);` will call the non-const version. Given the alternative, the non-const version takes precedence over the const one.

Comment: @MarcDuQuesne it's probably a good time now to review that the `const` version of your function that's causing this confusion doesn't need to exist.  It's only calling 2 public methods.  Copy (assignment) and the non-const rotate.

Comment: @Sarien Member functions have an implicit `this` parameter and `const` on member functions applies to the implicit `this`; i.e. `struct S { void foo() const; };` is kind of like `struct S {}; void foo(S const *this);`. Therefore just like `const` qualifiers on parameters the `const` takes part in both overload resolution and determining the type of the `this` parameter.

Comment: @bames53 I suppose it boils down to how to call the other function if the function that includes the const modifier would be preferred. :)

Comment: @Sarien I think it indicates a problem in the design of the overloaded functions if normal overload resolution does not pick the right function. In any case, the only way to select an overload would be to use manual type conversions, such as `const_cast`.

Comment: @bames53 I was looking at it from a more semantical point of view. If you have two functions and one of them does not mutate one of the parameters wouldn't that be preferable? Just like in the OP: "Well, I don't want to change this parameter so the function that doesn't change it should be used." But as I said it would leave us with the problem of how to call the other function if this was how it worked. So it seems that there is only one way and the OP will have to rename one of his functions.

Comment: @Sarien Renaming the functions is the correct thing in this case. Overloading is meant to be used for sets of functions that do the same thing but where different parameter types have to be taken into account. For example `T const &operator[](size_t) const` vs. `T &operator[](size_t)`. But the OP is overloading functions that do different things; his functions are like `operator+` and `operator+=`. These should not share the same name.

Comment: @Sarien: And why would the one that does not change any member be preferable?

Answer (score 1):

The return type does not participate in overload resolution. In other words you can't have functions that only differ in return type.

I think your code only compiles because one of those functions is "const".

Comment: I know. but the const makes a difference, and that's why the code compiles.

Comment: You can overload on constness.

Comment: There is no problem with the compiler, the overloads are legal because one of them is a `const` method and the other one isn't.

Answer (score 1):

if vector1 is not const ,it will choose

```
void Vector::Rotate(const double angle, Vector & axis)
```

for member function, there is a hiden parameter this,

```
Vector Vector::Rotate(const double angle, Vector& axis) const 
//actually is 
Vector Rotate(const Vector const * this,const double angle, Vector& axis) const 

void Vector::Rotate(const double angle, Vector & axis) 
//actually is 
void Rotate(Vector const * this,const double angle, Vector& axis)
```

the pointer of your object vector1  is `vector *`

I guess the compile will choose the best match one

Comment: see the comment on david's answer: why is that so? I thought declaring a method as const just prevents it from accidentally modifying a class's member variables. So, why does the call depend on the object?

Comment: I have changed my answer,hope it can explain it